# Can't see my PC on network, but can access it

Tags: networking, windows-10, file-sharing

This is rather inconvenience than a real problem.
I have 3 PCs connected on LAN & assigned to a Homegroup, but when I open network folder in explorer, I can only see 2 of them:

[Network folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGxii.png)

But when I manualy input `\\INTEL-PC` (PC name) into path, I can access it just fine (Both shared folders & printer):

[Missing PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jqua.png)

Moreover the same thing happens when I open network folder on the PC in question. The PC is unable to **see itself** in the network folder!

Is there some service than isn't running properly?

Comment: All PCs are running the same version of Windows?

Comment: 1 of them is 8.1, but not the "invisible" one